# Reference to external project doesn't work

Tags: android, android-library

Since I updated android SDK tools to rev19 my external Library Projects discontinued to be visible by referencing projects. 
With new dependency behavior I moved jars to /libs folder which has fixed references with external jars.

Addining a link to the LIbProject

[image]

Link added with the absolute path

[image]

When properties reopened again the link appears broken

[image]

This link helped with external jars. http://tools.android.com/recent/dealingwithdependenciesinandroidprojects

This is literally what I'm getting, not with jars but Library Projects.
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=27490

How to reference external projects now?

**Edit:**

Somehow reference to the Library Project is broken. From the referencing project I add link to a LibProject. Project->Properties->Android->Library->Add. When the lib project added, reopening properties shows that the link is broken. Projects are on different logical disks. If projects in a common root folder then linking works.

Comment: As long as you have set `Is Library` in the `Project->Properties->Android`, all you need to do is then add that project in the same place under the new project.

Comment: What "in the same place under the new project" does mean? Copy entire project into referencing project? Is any specific folder? It stoped to work after SDK update.

Comment: Sorry if that wasn't clear.  On the project that you want to have a reference to the library project, go to `Properties->Android`.  There is a `Library` section where you can define the project as being a library or the libraries it references.

Comment: That is how it was working until update happened.

Comment: I haven't had any problems after 19.  Are you compiling with Ant or Eclipse?  Maybe clean your projects.

Comment: With Eclipse. Seems tried everything. Thanks for trying to help.

Comment: Have you tried removing the references and then re-adding them (clutching at straws, sorry).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where to store the actual library project does not matter, as long as you use a **relative link** to reference it. Check out the [Library Projects - Development considerations](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/index.html#considerations):

> - #### Library project storage location
>
>   There are no specific requirements on where you should store a library project, relative to a dependent application project, as long as the application project can reference the library project by a relative link. What is important is that the main project can reference the library project through a relative link.

Check out my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10200751/eclipse-will-not-recognize-project-as-library-actionbarsherlock-viewpagerindica) to see the screenshot examine how correct (by using relative path) and broken (by using absolute path) library reference links are shown in Properties window.

Comment: I use ADT to add a link and it creates absolute path for the link

Comment: Probably because you use different logical disk, note that you are free to use Eclipse import different projects located under different logical disks in the same workspace, but this is something that ADT plugin doesn't really like. Honestly I don't know how to write a relative path point to some place under different logical disk. I think you have to move your library project into the same logical disk.