# "is library" project is red crossed

Tags: android

I am going to use "library" in "SHER" application. So I made "library" "is library" and used it in "SHER" app. by adding library:
[image]

When I look back, it is red crossed:
[image: image2]

I am using the ABS. I had imported all the applications from the downloaded "ABS".  Please help me

Comment: Obvious question. Is the library on its current path accessible?

Comment: You must use relative path to reference the library project, not absolute path. Check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10200751/eclipse-will-not-recognize-project-as-library-actionbarsherlock-viewpagerindica/10219498#10219498) for more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this means that the project cannot be found and there for you are referencing nothing.

you should remove the broken reference and import it again from the correct location

it can also mean that you removed the project referenced from your environment and you should either re-open the project or import it back to eclipse.

Comment: @SmartK8 yes, it is accessible and other applications are also accessing it  But for my  application,"library" is not accessible

Answer (score 1):

Select the row with the red line on it and click `Remove`. Then Click the `Add` button, and select `library` from the dialog box that opens to add the library project to your project, based on their current locations.

Answer (score 1):

It shows that the library where it lies at which path that path doesn't exists.

You need to first remove that library. Click on that library and select `Remove` button.

After that click on `Add` button ,and select your relevant library and add it into your application.

I hope this will help you.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just add the google-play-services.jar file in lib folder directly. Clean the project. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by imported the project and it's reference all together.

[image]

(Fig 1: Enter the path and click refresh to show all projects in that folder. Check the project and it's references)

[image]

(Fig 2: Reference project path become relative, and red cross didn't appear any more.)

I don't why importing reference project separately doesn't work. The only difference I guess were the paths.

Update:
checkout this post: [In eclipse, unable to reference an android library project in another android project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5167273/in-eclipse-unable-to-reference-an-android-library-project-in-another-android-pr)

Answer (score -1):

Red cross mean broken reference to solve that problem you should copy that library in workspace and then import that library in eclipse.

After that you can successfully use that library with green tick symbol in your project.

Comment: This does not add anything to the other answers