# eGit move project to a different location?

Tags: android, eclipse, git, egit

I was working on an Android project in Eclipse and I then decided to Git it. Being new, instead of creating a local repository in the parent of the project, I ended up creating it in `C:\Users\Little\.git\LocalRepository`.

Now, I am facing a lot of problems in my Android project; specifically with adding user libraries to my build path.

Based on this answer here:
[Eclipse will not recognize project as library (ActionBarSherlock/ViewPagerIndicator)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10200751/eclipse-will-not-recognize-project-as-library-actionbarsherlock-viewpagerindica)

I have imported all the user libraries to my workspace. However, my project itself is in a different folder and hence I am stuck. There is also a comment on the answer which says:

> Thanks. In my case, I forgot that my project was imported from git and
>   was physically located in another folder than all other projects.

I believe I have to do the same. **How do I get the project from local repo to my workspace?**

Comment: use  rm -rf .git to delte repo and clone it in dir u want

Comment: @adcom I have made one push to my remote repository after the local repo was created. So, I hope I wont screw things up when I delete it, will I? Maybe I should do another push just to be safe

Comment: do git status --> for more to be safe to git stash --> git pull --> git stash pop or u can rar ur repo and execute above command which i posted and clone rfersh repo in ur worksapce

Comment: @adcom Eclipse steps please :D I am learning Git command line but for now I will stick with Eclipse GUI

Comment: ohh u hv git bash? which os? ubuntu?windowS?

Comment: @adcom Windows 7 and Eclipse Juno

Comment: oh, sorry :( i m good at command line git.

Comment: @adcom I made a ZIP file, just to be safe. Will delete the local repo and clone it to the directory I want. If that fails, I will unzip it :D

Comment: yup , you willing to use command line ? then u can guide to right path . the command line config needs very less time that all pulgins mess in eclipse

Comment: @adcom I believe I need to switch to command line. I am learning that but just so I dont mess up my project, I stuck with GUI. Sure, point me in the right location.

Comment: if u delete ur local repo via delete button and build ur project there may be chance to build ur project in older location so make sure u delete via git command

Comment: @adcom Nope, it has the option to completely erase the files. Also, there was the option to import local repo into workspace. DANG!

Comment: :) coppied my answer !!! , u would hv said me to post it :) i would hv made ur job more easy :P

Comment: @adcom Have a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24823494/git-for-version-controlling-android-project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be below command help someone  to get rid of same issue with command line :

Step 1 : To make sure that ur git does not contains any local changes do :

```
git status
```

make sure here there is files where u have changes something and is in red color

Step 2: To check when and how commited last do :

```
git log
```

Step 3 :

```
rm -rf .git
```

Make sure u just take backup.

Step 4 : do git clone to dir u need :

```
git clone ssh://firstname.lastname@xx.x.xx.xx:xxxxx/project_name
```

Comment: Look at the other question I linked you to