# Git for version controlling Android project

Tags: android, eclipse, git, github

For some mysterious reasons, I ended up deleting my local repository. I now cloned my remote repo back into my Eclipse workspace and it shows that I am working on the master branch of my Android project rather than the local repo and it makes sense.

The reason why I started using Git is so that I can make wild changes to the project and if anything breaks, I can go back to the last stable state. Now, with a local repo gone and me working straight on my master branch of the project, I do not know how that can be done.

**Please tell me how that can be done.**

*PS: I need to have Android project in my workspace or else Eclipse starts complaining cause it cannot find user libraries*

Comment: you can make brach say masterbrach and dev barch : 

master brach means most stable code is in , dev brach means after any changes u willing to take backup u can push to dev brach and dont push to master until and unless u r sure of it

Answer (score 2):

If you cloned the remote repo back into your workspace, you have a local repo once more.
And you can always create new branches for your wild changes instead of working directly on the master branch.

Comment: yup thats what i said

Comment: Ok and where can I find the local repo? it is not in `C:\Users\Little\git` or the clone itself is the local repo? :)

Comment: where hv u clone new repo?

Comment: @adcom Into Eclipse workspace `E:\AndroidProjects` :)

Comment: then that ur repo and u can perform all git operations on it

Comment: @adcom Screw eGit I am going command line. Where do I get that for Windows?

Comment: @adcom Where can I find it for Windows?

Answer (score 2):

You can make brach say masterbranch and dev barch : master brach means most stable code is in , dev brach means after any changes u willing to take backup u can push to dev brach and dont push to master until and unless u r sure of it.

Create local brach

```
git checkout -b your_branch
```

Push it to the remote server.

```
git push <remote-name> <branch-name>
```